# Making baggy sweater that just sits over character

Tags: modeling, rigging

I'm trying to make a baggy sweater that just sits over top of this model.

Anybody have any pointers or articles that would help?

[image]

Comment: Create your cloth object, give it a Cloth physic, play the simulation so that the sweater falls on the body?